# What are the differences between the Yogacarin & Brahma Net Sutra Boddhisatva Precepts?

Tags: mahayana, bodhisattva, bodhisattva-vows

This [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=EZgdevTpySoC&lpg=PA121-IA2&dq=upasaka%20sutra&pg=PA121-IA2#v=onepage&q=upasaka%20sutra&f=false) link indicates that there is a version of the Bodhisattva Precepts with 4 major and 43 minor (as compared to 10 major and 48 minor in the BNS Bodhisattva Precepts). Does anyone know what these are?

I will also provide a link to [google](https://www.google.com/#q=yogacarin+bodhisattva+precepts) to demonstrate that google does not provide an answer since that seems to be a common answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you know the BNS precepts already, so you're asking about the Yogacara tradition.

I wonder whether [this](http://www.sutrasmantras.info/sutra31.html) might be close to what you'e looking for (4 major and 41 minor precepts).

> **The Four Major Precepts**
>
> Great Ones, the following four parājikas [grave sins] are in the
>   mātṛkā [collection of treatises] written by Bodhisattvas.
>
> 1. Praising Oneself and Criticizing Others
>      If a Bodhisattva, out of his greed for benefits, praises his own virtues and criticizes others, it is called the first parājika.
> 2. Begrudging Possessions or the Dharma
>      Suppose a Bodhisattva is well-to-do but stingy by nature. If he fails to invoke compassion and give poor people—who have nothing to
>      depend on—the things they ask for, or refuses to teach them when they
>      ask to hear the Dharma, it is called the second parājika.
> 3. Refusing to Accept Repentance
>      If a Bodhisattva, out of harming and terrifying anger, refuses to accept his offender’s repentance, uses abusive speech and, not feeling
>      satisfied, hits him with hands, clubs, or stones, it is called the
>      third parājika.
> 4. Maligning or Adulterating the True Dharma
>      If a Bodhisattva maligns Bodhisattva teachings, or pronounces supposedly similar dharmas and pretentiously establishes himself on
>      such dharmas, which come from his own or someone else’s understanding,
>      it is called the fourth parājika.

These precepts are in addition to the [four grave prohibitions](http://www.sutrasmantras.info/sutra33a.html#sup4):

> 4. The eight major precepts are the “four grave prohibitions” in the glossary, and the four major precepts in the Book of Bodhisattva Precepts (Sūtra 31).

[This link](http://www.dharmawheel.net/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=5810#p126158) says that's Yogācāra:

> What specifically are your concerns? I just looked at Rulu's translation of The Book of Bodhisattva Precepts and the four parājikas are the same as what is given in the Bodhisattvabhūmi of the Yogācārabhūmiśāstra.